# List<DBObject> casting to List<Category>

Tags: java

I have a super class `DBAdapter`, it have method `fetchAll()` which selects all records from the table of the DB to `List<DBObject>`. I have inherit this class with `CategoryDBAdapter`, this class knows about class `Category` extended from `DBObject`.

When I call:

```
CategoryDBAdapter categoryDbAdapter = new CategoryDBAdapter(dbHelper);

List<Category> categories = categoryDbAdapter.fetchAll();
```

my code can't cast `List<DBObject>` to the `List<Category>`. What is the common used way to resolve this collision?

Comment: Generics in Java are just fancy synaptic sugar that makes it so you don't have to cast to/from `Object` like we did when dinosaurs roamed the earth, and gives you some type checking at compile time. You can't cast a generic to another generic. You need to either redesign your classes or create a new Generic collection and copy/cast each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your DBAdapter and  DBCategoryAdapter classes to use generics:

```
class DBAdapter<T extends DBObject> {
    List<T> fetchAll() {
        ...
    }
}

class DBCategoryAdapter extends DBAdapter<Category> {

}
```

You would also need to adapt the content of the fetchAll() method, how easy this is depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think there is any direct way.** You need to create a new list for `Category` elements (`List<Category> categoryList`), iterate the list returned of `DBObject` elements(`List<DBObject> dbOjectsList`), cast the elements (`Category category = (Category) dbObject;`) and add to the new list list of category elements (`categoryList.add(category);`).

Comment: Thanks, I know this way, but I hope some universal and more efficient method exists. Or not?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko: I don't think that such method exists.